# Is there a counterpart of next()?

Tags: python, iterator

When reading through a file, I know it's possible to get the next line via `next()`, but is there a function like, say, `prev()` to go to the previous line?

In a similar vein, when looping through a file, is it possible to get the second line after the target line? `next()` will only return the line after as a string.

Comment: That would imply that Python is storing all of the previous state, which makes the principle of iterators somewhat pointless! Note that the one part of `itertools` that does this, `tee`, [specifically warns you about it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no counterpart. You can just store previous lines in a variable:

```
prev = None
for something in an_iterator:
    # do something with prev
    prev = something
```

For multiple items you could use a [`collections.deque()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

five_prev = deque(an_iterator, maxlen=5)
for something in an_iterator:
    five_lines_back = five_prev.popleft()
    # ...
    five_prev.append(something)
```

You cannot know what comes next until you retrieve it from the iterable, but you can certainly track what came previously.

You are not limited to calling `next()` once; if you need to retrieve two lines from the iterable, call `next()` twice, or use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) with `next()` to retrieve multiple items.

Comment: `You are not limited to calling next() once` - unless I'm mistaken, `r.next()` returns a string, and that's why `r.next().next()` returns an AttributeError that a string cannot have attribute 'next'

Comment: @sirius_pain: Call `r.next()` *again*. Not on the return value, on the iterator. And you want to use the `next()` function rather than call `.next()` on the iterator, so you can use the extra optional default argument to handle the case where your iterator is running out better. So use `next(r)` then `next(r)` again.

Comment: Now that you cleared that up with me, everything you've provided has worked. Thanks!